# Validating array of inputs using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I  hav  a rather large form it has 8 fields for entering books .
Now for user to add more books there is a button add more books ,on click of which a javascript function is called and  7 out of 8 fields are duplicated.

User can add maximum 6 books , and all the input fields created dynamically have their names as arrays . I am able to post them and store in a table , Now i want to validate them using javascript.

I have been tryng to do this since a week and am a new to Javascript . Please help me.

MY JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
function addInput(divName){
 var bname1 = new Array();
 var abname1 = new Array();
 var cost1 = new Array();
 var num1 = new Array();

 if (counter == limit) 
 {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else 
 {  
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML ="<table>"+ "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>"+ " Name of book" +  (counter + 1) + "  " +" : <input type='text' name='bname1[]' > "+"</td>" + "</tr>"+"<tr align='right'>"+ "<td>"+" Name of Authour"+(counter + 1)+" "+": <input type='text' name='aname1[]'>"+"</td>"+"</tr>"+"<tr align='right'>"+"<td>"+"Publisher"+(counter+1)+" "+": <input tyme='text' name='pub1[]'>"+"</td>"+"</tr>"+ "<tr align='right'>" +"<td>"+ "ISDN Number " + (counter + 1) +" "+ ": <input type='text' name='isdn1[]'> "+"</td>" + "</tr>"+"<tr align='right'>" +"<td>"+ " Edition " + (counter + 1) + " "+": <input type='text' name='edi1[]'> "+"</td>" + "</tr>"+"<tr align='right'>" + "<td>"+ "Price"+(counter + 1) +" "+ " :<input type='number' name='cost1[]'>"+"</td>"+"</tr>"+"<tr align='right'>" + "<td>"+ "Number of copies"+(counter + 1) +" "+ ": <input type='number' name ='num1[]'> "+"</td>" + "</tr>"+ "</table>";

    //  alert("counter +1 is "+counter+1);

      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
     counter=counter+1;



 }
}
```

there is divsion in the html form to which all this is added.
Please help !
thanx in advance ..

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? where's the validation code? what's the problem?

Comment: create a fiddle and explain u r question!!

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution. http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbq

HTML

```
<div id="testDiv">
</div>

<button onclick="addInput('testDiv')">
  Add New Items
</button>
<button onclick="validate('testDiv')">
  Validate
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 6

function addInput(divName) {
    var bname1 = new Array();
    var abname1 = new Array();
    var cost1 = new Array();
    var num1 = new Array();

    if (counter == limit) {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    } else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<table>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + " Name of book" + (counter + 1) + "  " + " : <input type='text' name='bname1[]' > " + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + " Name of Authour" + (counter + 1) + " " + ": <input type='text' name='aname1[]'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + "Publisher" + (counter + 1) + " " + ": <input tyme='text' name='pub1[]'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + "ISDN Number " + (counter + 1) + " " + ": <input type='text' name='isdn1[]'> " + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + " Edition " + (counter + 1) + " " + ": <input type='text' name='edi1[]'> " + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + "Price" + (counter + 1) + " " + " :<input type='number' name='cost1[]'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr align='right'>" + "<td>" + "Number of copies" + (counter + 1) + " " + ": <input type='number' name ='num1[]'> " + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>";

        //  alert("counter +1 is "+counter+1);
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter = counter + 1;



    }
}


    function validate(divName) {
        var container = document.getElementById(divName).getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var len = container.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // if only requried validation
            if (container[i].value == "") {
                container[i].style.borderColor = "red"
            } else {
                container[i].style.border = ""
            }


            //if you want saperate validation for each
            switch (container[i].name) {
            case "bname1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "aname1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "pub1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "isdn1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "edi1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "cost1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            case "num1[]":
                //validate according to filed
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot :) This worked for me :)) I am able to required validation  but for seperate validation ... I am nt able to access value of specific inputs .. I mean what to write in side Case "bname1[]": if("what to write here").... I am validating for length. Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions for you to consider:
1) consider grouping ALL the fields you want to duplicate inside a single div in your form.
Then when the user wants to add new item (book) all you will need to do will be copy the content of this div. This way you will maintain only one copy of field-set.
2) consider dynamic generic form validation too. You add the validation rules to your form field definition with extra attributes i.e. [<input ... validationRules="mandatory,minimumLength=10..." />] I think that you can achieve something similar with JQuery, but I personally prefer NOT to use large libraries to do small jobs.
3) consider giving your fields unique ids too.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var bname= document.getElementsByName('bname1[]');
var aname=document.getElementsByName('aname1[]'); .........

for(var i=0;i<bname.length;i++)
{
  //Your validations
}
for(var i=0;i<aname.length;i++)
{
  //Your validations
}.....
```

..
do this for all elements in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Validation function example:

```js
function validate_field(f) { // f is input element
    var name = f.name; // or also f.getAttribute('name')
    var value = f.value; // or also f.getAttribute('value'), but should be defined
    var error_div = document.getElementById(name+'err');
    //alert('name '+name+' value '+value);
    if (name.indexOf('bname') == 0) { // if validate book name
        if (value == '') { // e.g. book name should not be empty string?
            error_div.innerHTML = 'book name cannot be empty!';
            return false;  // field is wrong
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('aname') == 0) { // if validate author name
        if (value.length<2) {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'author\'s name is too short!';
            return false; // at least two characters long name? :)
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('pub') == 0) { // if validate publisher
        if (value.length<2) {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'publisher\'s name is too short!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('isdn') == 0) { // if validate ISDN Number
        if (value == '') {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'ISDN cannot be empty!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('edi') == 0) { // if validate Edition
        if (value == '') {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'edition cannot be empty!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('cost') == 0) { // if validate Price
        if (value=='') {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'Cannot be empty!';
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'Please write a price using digits!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (name.indexOf('num') == 0) { // if validate Number of copies
        if (value=='') {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'Cannot be empty!';
            return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            error_div.innerHTML = 'Please number of copies via digits!';
            return false;
        }
    }
    error_div.innerHTML = 'ok';
    return true; // field is ok
    // you can also have a look at http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
}
```

Full working script here: [pastebin.com/UkVP2uLb](http://pastebin.com/UkVP2uLb)